# Mapping/Defining a connection between the elements of a Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap containing attribute name and the list of possible attribute values in the form of normal distribution object. Now i want to define mapping between attributes i.e., if attribute 1 appears then atttribute3 and attribute 4 has to appear in my data set. I want to do it dynamically(not just by writing if else conditions because the size of HashMap will vary). Is there any possible way or library for doing this task? I don't have much experience with it and i am learning. Any pointer will be helpful.

```
HashMap<Attribute,List<NormalDistribution>> hmap = new HashMap<Attribute,List<NormalDistribution>>();//my hashmap
```

/* Data in my hashmap */

{@attribute Attribute4 numeric=[org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution@31befd9f, org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution@1c20c684], @attribute Attribute3 numeric=[org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution@13221655, org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution@2f2c9b19], @attribute Attribute2 numeric=[org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution@3af49f1c, org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution@19469ea2], @attribute Attribute1 numeric=[org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution@33c7353a, org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution@681a9515], @attribute Attribute0 numeric=[org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution@5b2133b1, org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution@72ea2f77]}

Comment: So you want to map an attribute to other attributes?
You might want to consider a graph data structure instead.

Comment: Yeah i want to map an attribute to other attributes. Ok i will try with graphs then @hbagdi

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to implement a specific solution. For example, create a new abstraction which encapsulates both the list of values and the related attributes:

```
public class AttributeSetup
{
    private final List<NormalDistribution> values;

    private final Set<Attribute> relatedAttributesSet;

    public AttributeSetup(List<NormalDistribution> values, Attribute... relatedAttributes)
    {
        super();
        this.values=values;
        this.relatedAttributesSet=new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(relatedAttributes));
    }

    public Set<Attribute> getRelatedAttributes()
    {
        return this.relatedAttributesSet;
    }

    public List<NormalDistribution> getValues()
    {
        return this.values;
    }
}
```

And then, replace in your map the mapped value by the new abstraction:

```
Map<Attribute, AttributeSetup> hmap=new HashMap<>();
```

How to use it? You have to populate the map in two phases:
First, create the attributes:

```
    Attribute attr1=new Attribute(...);
    List<NormalDistribution> values1=...;
    Attribute attr2=new Attribute(...);
    List<NormalDistribution> values2=...;
    Attribute attr3=new Attribute(...);
    List<NormalDistribution> values3=...;
```

Then, compose their relationships:

```
    hmap.put(attr1, new AttributeSetup(values1, attr2, attr3));
    hmap.put(attr2, new AttributeSetup(values2));
    hmap.put(attr3, new AttributeSetup(values3, attr1));
```

From then on, you can know the related attributes of a certain attribute upon the map:

```
    hmap.get(attr1).getRelatedAttributes();
```

Comment: I am implementing a specific solution. I am storing all the related attributes with their possible values in a List of Lists. Is there any performance differences in using ArrayList instead of sets as you specified in your solution(which one is better to use)? @LittleSanti

Comment: Yes, there is: A HashSet **indexes** its contained items, so accessing through `get` and `contains` is optimal versus an ArrayList, in which the equivalent access is **sequential** instead of indexed. The only requirements to make a HashSet work properly is to override `hashCode` and `equals` in the contained class, and to assume that each object can not be repeated within the same HashSet.

Comment: In fact, I chose `Set` for semantical reasons: I understand that an specific attribute cannot be related to another attribute more than once.

Comment: I need some help regarding for the removal of particular value from the above multi valued hashmap. I want to pick a random value from the Hashmap and want to store that value in a ArrayList and want to remove the copy of that value from the hashmap.

copy.get(childelement).remove(childsubelememtindex);
//childelement here is key let say Attribute3 from above hashmap
//childsubelememtindex is the index value of the of the sub list that belongs to the attribute 3 in my case it is either 0 or 1
but it is throwing "Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException"

Comment: Hum... A CME arises only when removing values while iterating a collection, or something like that. You should edit your question and post the failing program.